# Generator Function with existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, generator, yield

I have an object array with certain numbers id values.

I want to generate new id's or return the ones from the object array.

How can I do this using the generator function and yield?

example I tried:

```js
var array = [{'id': 0}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}];
function* idMaker() {
  var index = 0;
  array.forEach(object => {
    console.log(object.id);
  });
  while (index => o)
  yield index++;
}

var gen = idMaker();

console.log(gen.next().value); // 0
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
console.log(gen.next().value); // 3
console.log(gen.next().value); // 4
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a generator function to create new values or receive existing values from your data set ? Does it has to be a generator function ?

Comment: I totally agree with @DavidDomain. Generators are supposed to be used when you need fine tuning on the execution flow but it your case, I think it's just overkill, if you aren't forced to use that.

Comment: It's very funny how `while (index => o)` works out just fine.. you know that right..?

Comment: @Redu that's a type mistake, suppose to be 0.

Comment: @DavidDomain I needed it for generating new values and keep the state of value inside generator function. I will try a different method then, thanks.

Comment: It's more complicated than a simple typo. `index => o` is a function definition which  is a truty `!!(index => o)` is `true` and your `while` loop run as expected. I guess you just wanted to make `index >= 0`.

Comment: @Redu ah, your right.